# Overriding ToString() on a KeyValuePair<> struct

Tags: c#

As in the tile: overriding ToString() on the a KeyValuePair<> struct (System.Collections.Generic).I'm wondering if this can be done at all in C# (sealed structs).

Could anyone provide some insight or alternative approaches?

Or should I simply forget overriding and go for the following:

```
class MyKeyValuePair
{
    public KeyValuePair<T> Pair { get; set; }
    public MyKeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<T> pair)
    {
        this.Pair = pair;
    }
    public override ToString()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You cannot modify existing types, and `struct`s cannot be inherited.

Comment: Even the `MethodRental` class won't help here.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
static class KeyValueHelper
{
   public static string ToMyString<K, V>(this KeyValuePair<K, V> pair) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best you can do would be to create an extension method:

```
static class KeyValuePairMethods
{

    public static String ToCustomString<TK, TV>(this KeyValuePair<TK, TV> kvp)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Which could be called as:

```
new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Hello", 12).ToCustomString();
```

Of, course external code will still be using the ToString() method, so this probably won't be accomplishing anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` [can not be inherited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), therefore can't have its members overridden.

You would have to roll your own, as you suggest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this situation today, The `ToString()` method of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` returns something like `$"[{TKey.ToString()}, {TValue.ToString()}]"` so if your key and value are classes you can override the `ToString()` method of those classes to attain your preferred outcome for the `ToString()` method of `KeyValuePair<>`

source - [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.tostring?view=net-8.0#remarks)